# Purpose of QSGMII

Tags: mac, phy, sgmii

I do not understand the purpose of QSGMII. QSGMII is supposed to combine 4 SGMII signals from 4 MACs into 1 QSGMII signal at 5 GHz. However, there is no Ethernet standard that works at 4 (or 5) GHz. So the PHY will receive 4 times the normal flow and will not be able to do anything with it, unless the QSGMII is supplying 4 different PHYs.

Comment: qsgmii is a cisco proprietary thing, so they will surely have all kinds of interlinks and stuff that will work with it for connecting their own hardware.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the QSGMII, is as you write in your own question to substitute 4 SGMII interfaces.

4 SGMII interfaces mean 4 Tx and 4 Rx (8 in total) differential lines between the MAC and the PHY.

By grouping them in a QSGMII, only one SERDES interface is needed to be used, so only 1 Tx and 1 Rx (2 in total) differential lines are routed between the two sides.

And it is definitely not possible for a QSGMII to supply four different PHYs, since only 1 physical interface pro direction is used (as described above).

Also, your sentence "There is no Ethernet standard that works at 4 (or 5) GHz" doesn't make sense in the context. The PHY will receive data from four different MAC ports over the QSGMII interface, will then separate them and treat them, each, as a separate 1Gbps link.

**EDIT:**
The QSGMII interface is of course used at quad PHYs, meaning at PHYs that basically have four independent transceivers with four Ethernet copper/optical ports on the other (the non-MAC side). So each 1Gbps data flow from the MAC is mapped to one of these transceivers/ports and everything makes sense! Note, also, that it is quite common that quad PHYs that support QSGMII, also support alternatively four separate SGMII interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
But if a PHY receive 4 times the normal flow, it cannot send it through the Ethernet cable, so there will be an accumulation. Why concatenate 4 MACs flow if there is only 1 PHY that can not treat them?

Comment: Oh, I see now what you mean. There is a misunderstanding from your side! The PHYs that support QSGMII are PHYs that have 4 physical Ethernet ports on the other side! They are thus quad PHYs. So each 1Gbps data flow from the MAC is mapped to one of its four copper or optical Ethernet ports! It is also quite common that PHYs that support QSGMII, also support alternatively four separate SGMIIs.